# Cakephp with PHP7

Tags: php, cakephp-1.3, php-7

Can I run CakePHP 1.3 with PHP7? I have to do a migration to PHP7, but in the hosting there is a project in CakePHP 1.3 and need to know if there is any risk if I run this project in this version of PHP.

Comment: I don't think that's going to work since the latest cakePHP version is 1.3

Comment: Only actually running it will tell you whether it works. Even if Cake should be compatible, the code in the project may not be.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, unfortunately I can not run this project in another environment and needed to know if there is already some experience in running this version of CakePHP in version 7

Answer (score 9):

Unfortunately CakePHP 1.3 is not really compatible with PHP7 out of the box. I work on a old project in CakePHP 1.3 and my system upgraded to PHP7. There are a lot of [these](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.incompatible.php#migration70.incompatible.other.new-by-ref) in the core of CakePHP 1.3

After changing these, I ran into the next batch of errors, after which I rolled back and postponed the upgrade.

So to answer the question, it would be rather risky upgrading to PHP7 if there is a CakePHP 1.3 project.

Comment: I have finally got to upgrading my PHP. What's working for me is to run different versions of PHP through PHP-FPM and NGINX. I followed this guide mostly to get things working [link](https://kaustavdm.in/multiple-php-versions-arch-linux-php-fpm-nginx.html)

Comment: @Ale Sorry, I wasn't very clear about what I did. I made a second installation of PHP (PHP 5.6 specifically) on my system. So I have PHP 7 and 5.6 running at the moment. For my project that uses CakePHP 1.3, I changed my nginx web server to use the old version of PHP. So in my nginx.config I have something like `upstream oldphp { server unix:/run/php-fpm/php-fpm5.6.sock; }` and in my CakePHP 1.3 project's webserver config, I use `fastcgi_pass oldphp;`.

Comment: Ah ok, I understand now

Comment: I managed to get my CakePHP 1.3 project working under PHP 7. The only change I had to do was rename the "String" class and all it's uses to something else.

Comment: @PetarVasilev could you add a more detailed answer?

Comment: @icc97 I've added an answer

Answer (score 9):

If you are still looking for a CakePHP 1.3 port to PHP7, you are in luck!

I've ported [CakePHP 1.3.21 to PHP 7.3](https://github.com/littleant/cakephp-1.3.21), you can check it out on GitHub.

Please pay attention to the readme, as it naturally requires changes to your own code as well!

Answer (score 1):

I had to migrate a CakePHP 1.3 project to PHP7 and the only thing I did was find the "String" class and using PhpStorm's rename all occurrences feature I renamed it to "String_Renamed" that fixed the errors and everything worked afterwards. I've had no issues since.

Comment: I'm very surprised, because cake/libs/configure.php contains code like '$Folder =& new Folder();' - and throws fatal error due to syntax.