# CakePHP 1.3 and Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu, cakephp

I recently switched to a new Ubuntu 16.04 web server (on GCE) from an Ubuntu 14.04 server. I moved across a few Ruby on Rails projects that run on nginx and postgres with few problems. I now have two legacy CakePHP 1.3 apps to move over to the new server, but I am running in to PHP and MYSQL problems.

The old server was Ubuntu 14.04 running PHP 5.5 and MySQL 5.5.

Ubuntu 16 runs PHP 7, but since I read that [CakePHP 1.3 won't work on PHP7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35631341/cakephp-with-php7), I have downgraded to PHP 5.6.

But, I am still getting this error `"PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function mysql_query()"`

Is this because I am running mysql-5.7? Or is it still a problem with my PHP 5.6 installation?

I can get phpinfo to run. Here is a screenshot of the top of the result. 
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somewhere along the way of [downgrading PHP from PHP 7 to PHP 5.6](https://by-example.org/ubuntu-16-04-xenial-downgrade-php-7-to-php-5-6/) I missed a few php5.6 packages. I did the following:

```
sudo apt-get install php5.6-mbstring php5.6-mcrypt php5.6-mysql php5.6-xml
sudo service nginx restart
```

Now the old cakephp1.3 site is working fine on Ubuntu 16.

Also, note that since I am running CakePHP through nginx instead of the standard Apache setup, I needed to [customize my nginx configuration specifically for CakePHP](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation/url-rewriting.html#pretty-urls-on-nginx).